# Xamarin Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am a newbie to Mobile app development, Please help me to solve this problem.  I searched everywhere, but couldnt find any information in relation to this, which could solve the problem.

I am using Xamarin to develop iOS app, using Visual studio 2019 in Windows 10.  I connect to MacBook to work with it.  I have made sure, the firewalls dont block, so enabled the ipaddress and port.  When I try to send data (`Refer DeviceLogin method`) to my azure http trigger function (local), I get the following error.  My azure function works perfectly fine for android development.

```
    "LocalDataTask <CD65AF78-89E3-4B23-AFD7-58BF760241BC>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxx:xxx/api/RegisterDevice, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxx:xxx/api/RegisterDevice, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

I have also ensured to use NSUrl.  Check image.
[image]

```
var _httpClient = DependencyService.Get<ICustomHttpClient>().HttpClient;
public bool RegisterDeviceLogin()
        {
            var deviceData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "platformDeviceId", Constants.DeviceId }
            };

            var requestData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceData);
            
            var responseMessage = _httpClient
                .PostAsync(Constants.RegisterDeviceLoginUrl, new StringContent(requestData))
                .Result;
            return responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
```

Comment: there is a connectivity issue between the iOS Simulator/Device and your local Azure service

Comment: @Jason, can you help me solve it, what configuration should i need to set it up, so that i can get rid of this problem

Comment: this is basic network troubleshooting.  Can your device/emulator connect to to the machine running the service?  Use the device browser to test.  Is your service setup to handle remote requests?  If you are using a dev web server they are often only able to handle localhost requests by default.

Comment: @Jason, yes the device/emulator is able to connect to the machine running the service.  I don't see a prblem with the connection, this perfectly works for android, because of that, I opened firewall for my macbook ip address and opened the port number both inbound and outbound.  I also tried by disabling firewall completely.

Answer (score 0):

Create HttpClient in the FinishedLaunching override in AppDelegate as following and give it try:

```
var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
configuration.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = 360.0;
configuration.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 360.0;
HttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler(configuration));
```

Comment: sorry @Divyesh_08, still the same issue.  This did not resolve it.

Comment: I am wondering is it because it is in local ip address and iOS doesnt allow to interact?  While doing android development we can add a config file extension to include the local ip address.  Is there similar available for iOS development?

Comment: Have you added NSAppTransportSecurity in you info.plist? Add it once and try ir.

Comment: I did try with that, however still no success  ```  <dict>
     <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
     <dict>
         <key>http://xxxx:xxx</key>
         <dict>
             <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
             <string>TLSv1.0</string>
             <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
             <false/>
             <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
             <true/>
             <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
             <true/>
         </dict>
     </dict>
 </dict>```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem, my azure function runs on windows machine runs as localhost.  When I develop for iPhone using Xamarin, obviously I have to use Mac PC, which is where the problem is.  The iPhone from Mac cannot connect with http://localhost, so when we specify ipaddress instead of localhost, it can't find the my azure function running using the ipaddress.

One way I solved the problem is, running my azure function in MacBook as well, but ideally I would like to change my azure function to use ip address instead of localhost when working locally, or provide an option to change from localhost to ipaddress.